# What is the need of other Exception classes when Exception class alone can handle all type of exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

In one of my interviews the interviewer asked me a question about multiple `catch` blocks. The question was: Why do we need other child classes of `Exception`  to handle the exception, if the parent class, that is, `Exception`, alone can handle all other exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different advantages of using self written subclasses of Exception or RuntimeException:

- You can add additional information (Fields) to your Exception that you hand over to your logging. This can be useful for tracking your bugs more easily or to give your user some more information that he can provide you if his app is crashing
- You can distinguish different error reasons more easily and so decide how to solve different errorneous situations ( e.g. you could use an IllegalArgumentException if some argument you entered is wrong so you could prompt the user to enter a valid argument; On the other hand an IOException shows that you couldn't read/write your data at all)

Answer (score 1):

Because we can handle different exceptions in different way's, like:

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println("Everything is bad(");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I quote from the Basic Tutorial by Oracle

"In most situations, however, you want exception handlers to be as specific as possible. The reason is that the first thing a handler must do **is determine what type of exception occurred** before it can decide on the **best recovery strategy**. In effect, by not catching specific errors, the handler must accommodate any possibility. Exception handlers that are too general can make code more error-prone by catching and handling exceptions that weren't anticipated by the programmer and for which the handler was not intended."

See here for the complete text: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/advantages.html

Answer (score 0):

We use the subclasses of exception such as

```
FileNotFoundException
```

so that we get to display a proper message.

If we were to use only exception, when an application throws an exception, we would not know what the exception is.

This would not be very good for debugging. 
Using the child classes also helps us better log the exceptions.