# Exceptions in Java. What for do we have more than one checkable and one uncheckable class?

Tags: java

I’m a newcomer in Java programming. I’ve just started learning exceptions and I found in API documentation that all subclasses of Exception class have two constructors – one default and other with String parameter.

The difference between all these classes that some of them are checkable and other uncheckable. Uncheckable are not necessary to use and checkable have to be used. Am I right? If so, what for do we have more than one checkable and one uncheckable class?

For example, if we use `EOFException` class and `FileNotFoundException` class, what the difference between them except their names? Both have same constructors and both are checkable. I understand that methods which have possible situation of `EOF` throws `EOFException` because this name is logical and understandable in this situation. But what if we have opportunity to use `FileNotFoundException` instead `EOFException`? All the difference is a name.

If I want to create my own exception, what the difference if I extends `EOFException` class instead `FileNotFoundException` in situation when more logical would be extends `FileNotFoundException`? Is this no difference and just a good style of programming to use that exception class which name is more logical in current situation if both checkable?

Comment: A must read book for you, it covers this and a lot more: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Effective-Java-Second-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1466286081&sr=1-1&keywords=effective+java

Comment: Maybe if you continue reading, you'll find out why when you get to the `try-catch` statement, i.e. the language construct that *reacts* to exceptions.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Liskov Substitution Principle, and the ISA relationship in OO modelling?   (neither concept is Java specific, but they influence the design and use of the language very heavily).

Comment: Chris, how do you think if I have just started learning exceptions do I familiar with the Liskov Substitution Principle and the ISA relationship in OO modeling? Of course I do. And I even understand why you ask about it. Because in my question above I wrote in example about using superclass instead of its subclass. But if you were little bit attentively reading my question you could find out why (instead of telling me read the book from the beginning). Please if you don’t know the answer or don’t want to answer for “stupid” questions just don’t do it and don’t waste neither my time nor yours.

Answer (score 2):

You would use different names because lets say that you have a `FileReader`. If it throws `FileNotFoundException`, you know the file isn't found. But that is different from an `IOException` (even if FNFE extends `IOException`) because there are multiple things which would throw an `IOException`.

The different exceptions exist because you want to be able to deal with different problems, differently. Returning to that example above, if you have a `FileNotFoundException`, you could do something like write a default file or tell the user there is no file. But if you have an different exception, you could inform the user of whatever error that occurred.

The kinds of exception that do not need to be checked are runtime exceptions (and they all extend `RuntimeException`). Those exceptions exist because most of the time, they don't happen and it would be annoying to catch them if they happen so infrequently.

But if you're reading a file line by line from a `String[]` which you are not sure actually has a line 7 or something, you can then use your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` to deal with that problem. Similarly, `NullPointerException` deals with an entirely different problem. We cannot solve all these problems the same way, so different exceptions are used to tell the computer to do XYZ when a certain problem happens instead of YZX.

Comment: So, there is no difference between bodies of these classes (EOFException class and FileNotFoundException class) and we just use different names to make situation clearer?

Comment: `EOFException` tells you that an end of file or end of stream has been reached unexpectedly during input. `FileNotFoundException` tells you the file doesn't exist. How you want to deal with either of these problems is most certainly different – I mean, in one of them, the file exists! Because there is no way for the computer to magically solve the problem by itself, you catch and solve those exceptions. And because they are different problems, you solve them differently.

Comment: Ok, if classes have different tasks (one creates objects to deal with EOF and other when file not found) why do they have the same description in API? I can’t find difference between them except their names.

Comment: They don't have the same description. FNF says 'Signals that an attempt to open the file denoted by a specified pathname has failed'. EOF says 'Signals that an end of file or end of stream has been reached unexpectedly during input'. Docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html

Comment: Sorry, maybe I’m not correct in building my questions. I just try to find out difference between two classes, but all that I can see from API, they have the same constructors and yes, different description in words, but I want to see this difference in code. But all I see from API it’s the same constructors, so where can I find the difference in code between this to classes?

Comment: `catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // stuff to do } catch (EOFException e1) { // other stuff to do }`

Comment: Thank you for wasting your time for my stupid questions, but I mean difference not in try and catch block.
You said: «The different exceptions exist because you want to be able to deal with different problems, differently»

Comment: Ok. But where is the different between this to classes? I just can see class “A” that build some default object and object with string. And class “B” that does exactly the same. What the difference between their defaults objects? I can’t say without seeing code. What if this objects have the same semantics and there is no difference which of them to use? Or if they have different semantics where is this difference? Which fields are there, what is done in that constructor by default?

Comment: All I can see in API its name of constructor and parameters, that’s all. But what is there inside constructor? Does class “A” have the same body as class “B”? I hope no. If no this explain everything and topic can be closed.

Comment: FNF: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.java.html

Comment: You can also do this yourself in Eclipse. At a statement containing a `FileNotFoundException`, you can show the original class.

Comment: Thank you very much for this URL!!! Now I see that everything from subclass class is send up to superclass and so on unless we reach Throwable class.

Comment: I found what I want with your help. But now it’s make things go worse because I found that I was right and all these classes are different only by their names. All other are the same for them. They just send information through constructors up to the top of inheritance chain.

Comment: So we have to catch some exception exactly with the name “A” only because there is a method somewhere which throws “A”. But in deed created object by the class “A” is equal to the object created by the class “B”. Both of these objects are “empty” and just send information to their superclass.

Comment: So if I want to create my own exception I have to send all information to the superclass the same way and if both classes “A” and “B” are checkable I can extends one of them or directly IOException class, what the difference if both classes “A” and “B” are checkable and just send information up?

Answer (score 1):

*I have to rebuild my question to make it more clearly and protect from misunderstanding what exactly I ask. As result I received information what I want. And if someone has the same question you can find answer here.*

[Exceptions or how does it work from “inside”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934642/exceptions-or-how-does-it-work-from-inside)

*Also this partly helped:*

[What is the need of other Exception classes when Exception class alone can handle all type of exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329705/what-is-the-need-of-other-exception-classes-when-exception-class-alone-can-handl)