# Exceptions or how does it work from “inside”?

Tags: java

Here are two classes which are responsible for EOF and NFN exceptions:

```
public class FileNotFoundException extends IOException {

  public FileNotFoundException() {

    super();

  }

}

class EOFException extends IOException {

  public EOFException() {

    super();

  }

}
```

If we look through other subclasses of Throwable superclass the situation will be the same for most of them. Only default constructor which calls constructor of superclass and so on unless we reach the top of the inheritance chain.

I can’t understand where is logical part in code which is responsible for EOF or NFN situation? If the difference between them contains try and catch block then let’s try next:

```
try  {

  // code with possible IOException

}

catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

  // what to do if FNF has happened

}

catch(EOFException e) {

  // what to do if EOF has happened

}
```

Now let’s try to change FileNotFoundException with EOFException:

```
try  {

  // code with possible IOException

}

catch(EOFException e) {

  // what to do if FNF has happened

}

catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

  // what to do if EOF has happened

}
```

Both variants have to work in the same way because of their classes which are equal and do the same work – just call the constructor of their superclass.

So why we need two classes that do the same work?

P.S. the same question for most subclasses of Throwable class. Why don’t we just have two subclasses for Throwable class – one checkable and other uncheckable? What for do we need so many the same classes which do the same work – just call the constructor of their superclass?

Comment: Maybe so you can tell the difference between a FNF and an EOF?

Comment: If there was just one, you'd do `try {/* code with possible IOException */} catch(CheckedException e) {/* how do you tell whether an FNF happened or an EOF happened??? */}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the need of other Exception classes when Exception class alone can handle all type of exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329705/what-is-the-need-of-other-exception-classes-when-exception-class-alone-can-handl)

Comment: immibis I think about it. And I agree that this won’t be easy. If so we have to change the work of block catch and not let it use variables with the same name. Than it would be something like this:

Comment: try  {

  // code with possible IOException

}

catch(CheckedException e1) {

  // what to do if FNF has happened

}

catch(CheckedException e2) {

  // what to do if EOF has happened

}

Comment: But this won’t be as clear as current working variant. So what do we have? ))) Exception class alone can handle all type of exceptions but we need other Exception classes because its make more easier to read the code? If so, I was right in my previous topic where no one didn’t catch my mind and I created this one where I wrote in other words the same problem )))))))

Comment: Thank you Michael, it’s partly helped.

Answer (score 1):

> So what for do we need two classes that do the same work?

There are two distinct sets of **work** happening, there's the work that Java does for you when you throw an Exception ie capture the stack trace and unwind the stack etc. There's also the **work** that the application may or may not choose to do based on the **type** of the Exception, the Exception **type** is the clue to the developer where to put the code that does the **work** they need to do when catching a particular **type** of Exception. The **name** of the object allows you the developer to determine it's **type**. Note, the compiler doesn't care what the Exceptions are called ie the two Exceptions could just as easily have been called...

```
Exception65599
Exception1729
```

but humans don't deal well with names like this so they named them something sensible. Hence for each **type** of Exception we have in most cases sensible names and when a developer sees one of these names in documentation or code they know what that type signifies and what **work** they may need to do.

This also means that most Exceptions do very little that's different than the one they extend but the **type** is critically important.

[What's in a name? that which we call a rose By any other name would smell as sweet;](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_rose_by_any_other_name_would_smell_as_sweet)

Comment: So what do we have? ))) Exception class alone can handle all type of exceptions but we need other Exception classes because its make more easier to read the code?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty close. There are two Exception families, checked and unchecked and in each family the type tells you why it was raised and as a developer I now know what action I need to take based on the type of exception. Of course I could throw almost any exception type I want but typically I'm trying not to confuse the consumer of my code.

Comment: That’s it!!!!! Brilliant! That’s what I wanted to hear from the beginning. I told that everything could be done with two types – checkable and uncheckable. But this would be too difficult for human understanding that’s why we have a lot of the same subclasses with different names. Just to concretizes different exception situations and make them in this way more understandable for human! Am I right?

Comment: Here is my first attempt to read what you have written but as you see no one catch my mind:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901643/exceptions-in-java-what-for-do-we-have-more-than-one-checkable-and-one-unchecka

Comment: PS I have marked your answer as useful but my reputation as a newcomer is too low. It will appear little bit latter.

Answer (score 0):

The constructors you mentioned are all about creating these objects with the `new` operator. The 'logical part which is responsible for EOF or FNF situations' is in that code that creates and throws these objects with commands like `throw new FileNotFoundException();`

Comment: The command new FileNotFoundException() just created an object of FileNotFoundException class which is equal to class EOFException() because of reason mentioned above. If this is a logical part that’s mean that they have the same logic and one class just duplicate other.

Comment: What matters is the code that surrounds the command `throw new FileNotFoundException();` and the command `throw new EOFException();`.

I.e. `if (/*file is not available*/) {throw new FileNotFoundException();}else if(/*unexpected end of file*/) {throw new EOFException();}` so that a caller can white two different handlers for two different situations.